# jquery remember option selected

Tags: jquery

How to use jquery remember the option which user has previously selected when the from post to itself? (selected="selected")

```
<form action="abc.php" method="POST">
<select id="dropdown">
    <option value="A">A</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
    <option value="C">C</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Have you tried using cookies with jQuery?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458724/how-to-set-unset-cookie-with-jquery

Comment: @MarcoBerrocal I think the OP is talking about retaining form values on form submit.

Comment: Are you trying to submit the form with AJAX or just submitting it through http post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you *really* want to do it with JavaScript you'll have to use cookies. You can read about that [here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp). There are also cookie management plugins for jQuery, just google something along the lines of `jQuery cookie plugin`.

Otherwise, if you're returning to the form because some fields are not filled or a similar problem I suggest using PHP (as I see you're using it) to set the selected values.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your requirement correctly:

```
<form action="abc.php" method="POST">
<select id="dropdown" name="dropdown">
    <option <?php if(isset($_POST['dropdown']) && $_POST['dropdown'] == 'A') echo 'selected="selected"';?> value="A">A</option>
    <option <?php if(isset($_POST['dropdown']) && $_POST['dropdown'] == 'B') echo 'selected="selected"';?> value="B">B</option>
    <option <?php if(isset($_POST['dropdown']) && $_POST['dropdown'] == 'C') echo 'selected="selected"';?> value="C">C</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

PS : You'll also need a `name` attribute for the `select` tag if you're using PHP to submit the form. Also I'm assuming `abc.php` is the same page in which this form is present.